# Adding already created objects to my Java Array

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, matrix

I created 5 objects from the class Medicos, and 5 objects from the class Enfermeras, how do i add these already created elementos an array?

**Array Class:**

```
public class Metodos {

    private Medicos [] ListaM = new Medicos [5];
    private Enfermeras [] ListaE = new Enfermeras [5];
    private Clinica [][] datos = new Clinica [12][30];

    public Metodos(){
        ListaM[0] = Medicos() = Medico1; 
    }
}
```

**Medicos Class:**

```
public class Medicos {

    private String Nombre;
    private long DPI;
    private String NIT; 
    private boolean Especialista; 
    private int nColegiado;
    private int salario; 

    public Medicos(String Nombre, long DPI, String NIT, boolean Especialista, 
            int nColegiado, int salario){ 
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.DPI = DPI; 
        this.NIT = NIT ; 
        this.Especialista = Especialista; 
        this.nColegiado = nColegiado; 
        this.salario = salario; 
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }
    public long getDPI() {
        return DPI;
    }
    public void setDPI(long dPI) {
        DPI = dPI;
    }
    public String getNIT() {
        return NIT;
    }
    public void setNIT(String nIT) {
        NIT = nIT;
    }
    public boolean isEspecialista() {
        return Especialista;
    }
    public void setEspecialista(boolean especialista) {
        Especialista = especialista;
    }
    public int getnColegiado() {
        return nColegiado;
    }
    public void setnColegiado(int nColegiado) {
        this.nColegiado = nColegiado;
    }
    public int getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }
    public void setSalario(int salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    Medicos Medico1 = new Medicos("Juan Pérez", 1234567870101L, "6799652-3", true, 
            89098, 15000);

    Medicos Medico2 = new Medicos("Luis Gutiérrez", 9876543260101L, "8964547-3", false, 
            98554, 12000);

    Medicos Medico3 = new Medicos("Eduardo González", 5642871750101L, "8786456-6", true, 
            5653, 17000);

    Medicos Medico4 = new Medicos("Guadalupe Torres", 4562973920101L, "6799652-3", true, 
             10098, 17000);

    Medicos Medico5 = new Medicos("María Castillo", 569395290101L, "8765485-7", false, 
             67965, 13000);
}
```

**Enfermeras Class:**

```
public class Enfermeras {

    private String Nombre;
    private long DPI;
    private String NIT; 
    private boolean Intensivista; 
    private int experiencia;
    private int salario; 

    public Enfermeras(String Nombre, long DPI, String NIT, boolean Intensivista, 
            int experiencia, int salario){ 
        this.Nombre=Nombre;
        this.DPI = DPI; 
        this.NIT = NIT; 
        this.Intensivista = Intensivista; 
        this.experiencia = experiencia; 
        this.salario = salario; 
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return Nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        Nombre = nombre;
    }
    public long getDPI() {
        return DPI;
    }
    public void setDPI(int dPI) {
        DPI = dPI;
    }
    public String getNIT() {
        return NIT;
    }
    public void setNIT(String nIT) {
        NIT = nIT;
    }
    public boolean isIntensivista() {
        return Intensivista;
    }
    public void setIntensivista(boolean intensivista) {
        Intensivista = intensivista;
    }
    public int getExperiencia() {
        return experiencia;
    }
    public void setExperiencia(int experiencia) {
        this.experiencia = experiencia;
    }
    public int getSalario() {
        return salario;
    }
    public void setSalario(int salario) {
        this.salario = salario;
    }

    Enfermeras Enfermera1 = new Enfermeras("Juana Lopez", 5643213450101L, "563269-K", false, 
            2, 6000);

    Enfermeras Enfermera2 = new Enfermeras("Lidia Mendez", 1246547850101L ,  "7654376-6" , true, 
            2, 9000);

    Enfermeras Enfermera3 = new Enfermeras("Miriam García", 6547854370101L, "9876456-8" , false, 
            14, 8000);

    Enfermeras Enfermera4 = new Enfermeras("Lorna Suarez", 569374160101L, "4567865-8" , true, 
            12, 10000 );

    Enfermeras Enfermera5 = new Enfermeras("Mariela Rodríguez",3254786540101L, "6789654-8" , false, 
            2, 8000 );
}
```

Im really lost here and cant seem to find a proper answer, help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to follow java naming conventions of keeping variable name as camelcase.

secondly,Adding the object to an array is just assigning it to each element of an array like,

```
ListaM[0] = Medico1;

ListaM[1] = Medico2;
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can do it. One way is to make your arrays in the Metodos Class, public static.

So that from your Medicos / Enfermeras class you can simply assign the object into the array in Metodos class.

e.g. for the Metodos class
change this

```
private Medicos [] ListaM = new Medicos [5];
```

to

```
public static Medicos [] ListaM = new Medicos [5];
```

e.g. for the Medicos class

```
Medicos Medico1 = new Medicos("Juan Pérez", 1234567870101L, "6799652-3", true, 
                    89098, 15000);

// After Creating the object, assign it        
Metodos.ListaM[0] =  Medico1 ;
```

The other way is, you should have just create the object from the Metodos class itself.

e.g. in the Metodos class.

```
 public Metodos(){
      Medicos Medico1 = new Medicos("Juan Pérez", 1234567870101L, "6799652-3", true, 
                89098, 15000);
            ListaM[0] = Medico1 ; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Medico1,Medico2 ... are decleared as default fields , not static , so you need to access it via an instance of their class .
If you want to put two different kinds of objects into one array , you need to declear the array as their super class , say `Object`.

```
        Object[] objs = new Object[10];
        Medicos medicos = new Medicos("",0,"",false,0,0);
        objs[0] = medicos.Medico1;
        objs[1] = medicos.Medico2;
        ...
        Enfermeras enf = new Enfermeras("",0,"",false,0,0);
        objs[5] = enf.Enfermera1;
        ...
```